# Instantiating an array in a class and then creating an object of that class with the values for that array

Tags: c++, class

So I've been trying to get a hold of the C++ syntax coming from python and I decided to do that by replicating a little library I wrote for handling exponentials in python. But I've been running into this oddity that I just don't really understand. Here's the 'simplified' code.

```
using namespace std;
int exponential_input_array[] = {6,7,16};

class exponential{
  private:
    double a_1;
    double a_2;
    int list[2] = {};
  public:
    void initialize(int list_[]){
      list_ = list;
      list[0] = a_1;
      list[1] = a_2;
    }
    int print_data(){
      cout << "a_1 is: " << a_1 << endl;
      cout << "a_2 is: " << a_2 << endl;
      return 0;
    }
};
int main(){
  exponential exponential_object;
  exponential_object.initialize(exponential_input_array);
  exponential_object.print_data();
}
```

Now I'm trying to print out the 0th and 1st element of the array and I expect that to be 6 and 7 but instead it prints out:

```
a_1 is: 9.88131e-324
a_2 is: 4.65551e-310
```

I don't get why I'm getting these values...

Comment: In C++ use `std::vector` to represent arrays. Unlike C-style arrays (`list[]`) these can be copied using `=`. If you only have two entries you may even want to use `std::tuple`, or just pass them in as two individual arguments.

Comment: @tadman "*In C++ use `std::vector` to represent arrays*" - or `std::array`, if the number of elements is known at compile-time. `std::vector` is for when the number of elements is not known until runtime

Comment: Where in your program do you initialize `a_1` and `a_2`?

Comment: @RSahu ah, I see.

Comment: [What is the default value for C++ class members](//stackoverflow.com/a/2614902)

Comment: @RemyLebeau True, though `std::vector` works in most situations. `std::array` is useful in *some* situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `initialize()` method is implemented backwards.

It is trying to assign the member `list[]` array to the input parameter `list_`, which "works" only because `int list_[]` is the same as `int *list_` in a function parameter, and an array *decays* to a pointer to its 1st element. But the code is not actually copying any values from `list` to the array pointed by `list_` (or vice versa).

But also, the code is trying to assign the values of `a_1` and `a_2` to the member `list[]` array, rather than the other way around.  `a_1` and `a_2` are *uninitialized* when `print_data()` is called.

`initialize()` should look like this instead:

```cpp
using namespace std;
int exponential_input_array[] = {6,7,16};

class exponential{
  private:
    double a_1;
    double a_2;
    int list[2] = {};

  public:
    void initialize(int list_[]){ // <-- same as int* list_ ...
      // cant assign an int* to an int[], so copy the values manually...
      for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) { list[i] = list_[i]; }
      or:
      std::copy(list_, list_+2, list);

      a_1 = list_[0];
      a_2 = list_[1];
    }

    int print_data() const {
      cout << "a_1 is: " << a_1 << endl;
      cout << "a_2 is: " << a_2 << endl;
      return 0;
    }
};

int main(){
  exponential exponential_object;
  exponential_object.initialize(exponential_input_array);
  exponential_object.print_data();
}
```

Output:

```
a_1 is: 6
a_2 is: 7
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/AGkRyJ)

That being said, the logic of `initialize()` should be handled by `exponential`'s constructor instead of a separate method, eg:

```cpp
using namespace std;
int exponential_input_array[] = {6,7,16};

class exponential{
  private:
    double a_1;
    double a_2;
    int list[2] = {};

  public:
    exponential(int list_[]){ // <-- same as int* list_ ...
      // cant assign an int* to an int[], so copy the values manually...
      for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) { list[i] = list_[i]; }
      or:
      std::copy(list_, list_+2, list);

      a_1 = list_[0];
      a_2 = list_[1];
    }

    int print_data() const {
      cout << "a_1 is: " << a_1 << endl;
      cout << "a_2 is: " << a_2 << endl;
      return 0;
    }
};

int main(){
  exponential exponential_object(exponential_input_array);
  exponential_object.print_data();
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/lBL9TE)

Comment: Thank you, this was a great explanation, it clarifies so much.

Answer (score 1):

Problems I see:

1. `a_1` and `a_2` are not initialized when the object is default constructed.
2. `list_ = list;` changes `list_` such that it points to the first member of `list`. It does not change `list`, which I think is your intent.
3. The lines

   ```
    list[0] = a_1;
    list[1] = a_2;
   ```

   set the values of `list[0]` and `list[1]` to uninitialized values. Now you have garbage values not only if `a_1` and `a_2` but also in `list[0]` and `list[1]`.

My suggestion:

Use a constructor that initializes all member variables correctly.

```
class exponential{
  private:
    double a_1;
    double a_2;
    int list[2] = {};
  public:

    exponential(int list_[]) : a_1(list_[0]), a_2(list_[1])
    {
       std::copy(list_, list_+2, list);
    }

    int print_data(){
      cout << "a_1 is: " << a_1 << endl;
      cout << "a_2 is: " << a_2 << endl;
      return 0;
    }
};

int main(){
  exponential exponential_object(exponential_input_array);
  exponential_object.print_data();
}
```